# There is no formatter for 'java' files installed in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, format, ide, pretty-print

I was able to format Java code in VSCode, but now I see "there is no formatter for 'java' files installed." as:

[image: screenshot]

Certainly language support is provided through the redhat language support plugin.  Can this be re-initialized, perhaps?

Looks to be a [problem](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/610) others have at least seen, although the error message might be slightly different.

Version info:

```
Version: 1.41.1
Commit: 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
Date: 2019-12-18T15:04:31.999Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.18.0-25-generic snap
```

Comment: you may try to use the shortcut key `shift + alt + F `

Comment: Could you please check if there is any other java related extension? Uninstall them if there is. And reload vscode and try again.

Comment: I'll remve the different extensions, they may be causing a problem @ElvisXia-MSFT

Comment: You solved the issue ?

Comment: Every time I open vsCode  it says there is no formatter installer for "language" , but after a while it loads formatter. So i think wait for a while after starting vs code  may helpful

Answer (score 2):

Everything worked fine until today. I didn't update or change anything in vs code.
But today I had the same error for typescript files:
"Sorry, but there is no formatter for 'typescript'-files installed"
Explicitly setting typescript.format.enable to true fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Check your settings.json (mine was in .vscode). Update this to:

```
"java.format.enable": true,
```

Mine was set to false.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Disable All Installed Extensions and then click on Enable All Extensions